# Change string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var a = "Text(money ='3/3/dollor',unit=42)";
```

I want to get rid of  `money ='3/3/dollor',`

Using javascript, how to do this?

Sorry I did not make this very clear, the string after money = can be anything but they are string for sure, and always ends up with an comma.

More samples

```
var a = "Text(money ='v23f3/.3/dollor',unit=42)";
var a = "Text(money ='3/3fds/d.ollor',unit=42)";
var a = "Text(money ='3.3.3.3/3/d.o/l.lor',unit=42)";
var a = "Text(money ='3/3/dollor',unit=42)";
```

The output I need is  `a = "Text(unit=42)"`

Comment: @user469652: The single quoted substring (`money = '...'`) could contain commas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = a.replace(/money ='.*',/, "");
```

Comment: I need a generic way to do this, the string after "money =" could be anything.

Comment: @user469652 - you need to be more specific about all the possible combinations, words, letters there are. provide like 5-10 different examples of strings.